# not able to map array value in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am getting below value in the props "ticketDetailsInfo" and after that I am taking followupDetails array ,below is the value of followupDetails which is coming from server . ,but when amd doing maping followupDetails.map() its throwing error followupDetails.map() is not a function . While I have to take array value and display in ui . Please correct me where I am going wrong .

// Array Value is

const{ticketDetailsInfo}=this.props

const{troubleTicketDetails,workFlowDetails,followupDetails} =ticketDetailsInfo;

```
 "followupDetails": [
            {
              "INCIDENTNUMBER": "16739",
              "INCIDENTINITIATOR": "U",
              "INCIDENTTIMESTAMP": "06/06/2019 16:25:36",
              "NOTES": "Test",
              "USERID": "597",
              "STATUSUPDATED": null,
              "USERGROUPNAME": "clmui",
              "BINARYOBJECT": "N"
            },
            {
              "INCIDENTNUMBER": "16738",
              "INCIDENTINITIATOR": "E",
              "INCIDENTTIMESTAMP": "06/06/2019 16:25:36",
              "NOTES": "Test",
              "USERID": "597",
              "STATUSUPDATED": null,
              "USERGROUPNAME": "clmui",
              "BINARYOBJECT": "N"
            }
          ],

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ImageBackground, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { Body, Button, Card, CardItem, Text, View } from 'native-base';
import styles from '../requestTab/TroubleTicketDetails.style';
import Header from '../../ui/header';
import BG from '../../../images/bg.jpg';
import { IconNormal } from '../../ui/icons';
import _ from 'lodash';
import { RegularText, SmallText } from '../../ui/text';
import StepIndicator from 'react-native-step-indicator';
import LoadingSpinner from '../../ui/spinner';

class TroubleTicketDetails extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const {MSISDN,ticketDetailsInfo} = this.props;

    this.state = {
      title: 'Trouble Ticket',
      icon: "sim",
      mobile: MSISDN,
      StepsVaue:[],
      Steplabels:[],
      currentStepPosition:[],
      SteplabelconcatValue:[],
      SteplabelsTimes:[]
    };
  }

  iconSymbol = (priority) => {
    let symbol = '';
    let color = '';
    if (priority === '10') {
      symbol = 'exclamation';
      color = 'red';
    } else if (priority === '1') {
      symbol = 'arrowdown';
      color = 'white';
    } else {
      symbol = '';
      color = '';
    }
    return { symbol: symbol, color: color };
  };

  componentDidMount() {}

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {}

  componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo) {
    console.log("TroubleTicketHistory Error", error);
    console.log("TroubleTicketHistory ErrorInfo", errorInfo);
  } 

  loadScreen() {
    //RedirectScreen(this.props.navigation, 'SimSwap', this.state);
  }

  renderLabel = ({ position, stepStatus, SteplabelsTimes, currentPosition }=this.state) => {

    return (
      <Text
        style={
          position === currentPosition  ? styles.stepLabelSelected  : styles.stepLabel
        }
      >
        {SteplabelsTimes}
      </Text>
    )

  }

  render() {

    let { title, mobile, icon, currentStepPosition, Steplabels } = this.state;
    let { navigation,ticketDetailsInfo,referenceNumber,TICKET_TYPE_DESCRIPTION,priority, currentStatus,convertedDate } = this.props;
    const{troubleTicketDetails,workFlowDetails,followupDetails} =ticketDetailsInfo;
    console.log("followupDetails" , followupDetails)

    StepsVaue = workFlowDetails.currentNextActivity;

      Steplabels = StepsVaue.map(StepsVaue => {
           return StepsVaue._activityName;
    });

    SteplabelsTimes = StepsVaue.map(StepsVaue => {
      return StepsVaue._maxHoldTime;
});
    // SteplabelconcatValue = StepsVaue.map(StepsVaue => {
    //   return StepsVaue._activityName.concat("_",StepsVaue._maxHoldTime);
    // });

    currentStepPosition = StepsVaue.filter((item) => {
      return item._activityStatus === "I"
});

const stepIndicatorStyles = {
      stepIndicatorSize: 30,
      currentStepIndicatorSize:40,
      separatorStrokeWidth: 1,
      currentStepStrokeWidth: 5,
      stepStrokeCurrentColor: '#fe7013',
      separatorFinishedColor: 'black',
      separatorUnFinishedColor: 'black',
      stepIndicatorFinishedColor: 'green',
      stepIndicatorUnFinishedColor: '#aaaaaa',
      stepIndicatorCurrentColor: '#ffffff',
      stepIndicatorLabelFontSize: 0,
      currentStepIndicatorLabelFontSize: 0,
      stepIndicatorLabelCurrentColor: '#000000',
      stepIndicatorLabelFinishedColor: '#ffffff',
      stepIndicatorLabelUnFinishedColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)',
      labelColor: 'black',
      labelSize: 15,
      currentStepLabelColor: 'black'
    }

    if(!_.isEmpty(referenceNumber) && (StepsVaue[0])) {

    return (

      <ImageBackground source={BG} style={styles.imgBG}>
        <ScrollView>
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <View>
              <Header title={title} subtitle={mobile} icon={icon} navigation={navigation}/>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
              <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>
                <View style={{marginBottom: 10}}>
                    <Card>
                      <CardItem header style={{backgroundColor: '#23476B', width: '100%', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
                        <View style={{flexDirection:'column'}}>
                          <View>
                            <RegularText text={`${TICKET_TYPE_DESCRIPTION} ID : ${referenceNumber}`} textColor='#fff' style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}/>
                          </View>
                          <View>
                            <SmallText text={`Raised ${convertedDate}`} textColor="#fff"/>
                          </View>
                        </View>
                        <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
                        <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
                      <IconNormal icon={this.iconSymbol(priority).symbol} type="AntDesign" style={{ color: this.iconSymbol(priority).color , paddingTop: 5}}/>
                      </View>
                        {/* <IconNormal icon={this.iconSymbol(priority).symbol} type="AntDesign" style={{ color: this.iconSymbol(priority).color , paddingTop: 5}}/> */}
                        <View style={{backgroundColor:'orange', borderRadius:50,height: 28, paddingRight: 10, paddingLeft: 10, paddingTop: 5}}>
                          <SmallText text={`${currentStatus}`} textColor='white'/>
                        </View>
                        </View>
                      </CardItem>
                      <CardItem>
                        <Body>
                          <View style={{flexDirection:'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', width: '100%'}}>
                            {/* <View style={{flexDirection:'column'}}>
                              <View>
                                <SmallText text="Catagory" textColor="grey"/>
                              </View>
                              <View>
                                <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize:14 }}>{troubleTicketDetails.cat1}</Text>
                              </View>
                            </View> */}
                            {troubleTicketDetails.cat2.length > 0 && 
                            <View style={{flexDirection:'column'}}>
                              <View>
                                <SmallText text="Sub-Category" textColor="grey"/>
                              </View>
                              <View>
                                <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize:14 }}>{troubleTicketDetails.cat2}</Text>
                              </View>
                            </View>}
                            {troubleTicketDetails.cat3.length > 0 && 
                            <View style={{flexDirection:'column'}}>
                              <View>
                                <SmallText text="Sub-SubCategory" textColor="grey"/>
                              </View>
                              <View>
                                <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize:14 }}>{troubleTicketDetails.cat3}</Text>
                              </View>
                            </View>}
                          </View>
                        </Body>
                      </CardItem>
                    </Card>
                  </View>
                <View>
                  <RegularText text={`WORKFLOW`} textColor='grey' style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', textAlign:'center', marginBottom:10 }}/>
                </View>
                <View style={{borderWidth:1, borderColor:'lightgrey', borderBottomColor:'white', padding:10, flexDirection:'column'}}>
                    <Card>
                      <CardItem>
                        <Body style={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                            <View style={{flexDirection:'column'}}>
                              <RegularText text={` ${workFlowDetails.WRKFLW_DESC_V}`} textColor='green' style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}/>
                            </View>
                            <View style={{flexDirection:'column'}}>
                              <SmallText text={`Time Remaining is ${workFlowDetails.ESTIMATED_RESOLN_TM_N} Hours`} textColor='green' style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}/>
                            </View>
                        </Body>
                      </CardItem>
                    </Card>
                </View>
                <View style={{paddingLeft:10, height:300, marginBottom:10, borderWidth:1, borderColor:'lightgrey', borderTopColor:'white'}}>
                  <StepIndicator
                       customStyles={stepIndicatorStyles}
                       currentPosition={currentStepPosition.length}
                       stepCount={Steplabels.length}
                       labels={Steplabels}
                       renderLabel ={this.renderLabel()}
                       direction="vertical"
                  />
                </View>
                <View>

                  <RegularText text={`NOTES`} textColor='grey' style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', textAlign:'center', marginBottom:10 }}/>
                </View>


                <View style={{marginLeft:10,marginRight:10}}>

                {Array.isArray(followupDetails) && followupDetails.map(
                  ({  INCIDENTINITIATOR, INCIDENTTIMESTAMP,NOTES, USERGROUPNAME}, index) => {
                    var INCIDENTINITIATOR_Value;
                    if(INCIDENTINITIATOR =="U"){
                      INCIDENTINITIATOR_Value ="USER";
                    }
                    else{
                      INCIDENTINITIATOR_Value ="CUSTOMER";
                    }


                       <View style={{marginBottom: 10}} key={index}>
                    <Card>
                      <CardItem header style={{backgroundColor: '#fff',  justifyContent: 'space-between', borderBottomColor: '#f1f1f1', borderBottomWidth: 1}}>
                      <View style={{flexDirection:'column'}}>
                          <View style={{backgroundColor:'lightgrey',  borderRadius:50,height: 28, paddingRight: 10, paddingLeft: 10, paddingTop: 5}}>
                            <SmallText text={`${INCIDENTINITIATOR_Value}`} textColor='grey'/>
                          </View>
                          <View>
                            <Text style={{ fontSize:14 }}> {NOTES} </Text>
                          </View>
                        </View>
                      </CardItem>
                      <CardItem>
                        <Body>
                          <View style={{flexDirection:'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', width: '100%'}}>
                              <View>
                                <SmallText text={`${USERGROUPNAME}`} textColor="grey"/>
                              </View>
                              <View>
                                <SmallText text={`${INCIDENTTIMESTAMP}`} textColor="grey"/>
                              </View>
                          </View>
                        </Body>
                      </CardItem>
                    </Card>

                    </View>


                     })
                    }
                    </View>}




                  {/* <Button block bordered dark>
                    <Text>Add a Note</Text>
                  </Button> */}
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </ImageBackground>
    );

  }else{
    return(
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <LoadingSpinner color="#00678F"/>
    </View>
    )
  }
  }
}
 /*<IconNormal icon={this.iconSymbol(priority).symbol} type="AntDesign" style={{ color: this.iconSymbol(priority).color , paddingTop: 5}}/> */

export default TroubleTicketDetails;
```

Thanks

Comment: Where is the code where you set followupDetails? Looks like it could be a promise or the value is not set because the request is not resolved yet.

Comment: followupDetails is array that I am getting in the props .. I am doing followupDetails.map() and after that in view I am displaying that value .. Please correct me if I am doing wrong

Comment: Can you do console.log(followupDetails) and let us know what is getting displayed? In that way we can figure out if there is an issue with props being passed.

Comment: Sir whatever I have written in above question followupDetails array value that is coming in console

Comment: I asked for the code where you set followupDetails, you already stated it comes from props in the question but the code where you set the props is missing (container or parent component).

Comment: followupDetails  is not an array, its object containing an array of object you need to do Object.values on followupDetails